# string parsing a complex logical operators in pyparsing

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, query-string, pyparsing

i am trying parse logical operators, query string see below

```
code!=720 AND first_name=abc OR last_name=def AND status_code=OK
```

and get the parsed string as a binary tree. For the above expression the expected parsed expression should look like

```
[[['code', '!=', '720'], 'AND', ['first_name', '=', 'abc']], 'OR', [['last_name', '=', 'def'], 'AND', ['status_code', '=', 'OK']]]
```

i tried to do this code but i do not get the desired output

```
operator = pp.Regex(">=|<=|!=|>|<|=").setName("operator")
number = pp.Regex(r'[+-]?\w+(:?\.\w*)?(:?[eE][+-]?\w+)?')
word = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums + "_-*(1234567890 ,)")
term = word | number
condition = pp.Group(term + operator + term)


expr = pp.operatorPrecedence(condition,
         [('NOT', 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT,),
          ('AND', 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT,),
          ('OR', 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT,)])
```

example

```
query_string = 'code!=720 AND first_name=abc OR last_name=def AND status_code=OK'
print(expr.parseString(query_string)[0])
```

and output is wrong

```
 [['code', '!=', '720'], 'AND', ['first_name', '=', 'abc OR last_name']]
```

can you help me write the correct condition?

Comment: Do not include the space character in the definition of `word`. If you want to allow values with embedded spaces, enter them as quoted strings (and add pp.quotedString as an alternative in `term`). Also, call `parseString` with `parseAll=True` to flag errors due to unmatched text after the parser thinks it is done.

Comment: @PaulMcG can you show me example?

Comment: `word=pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums + "_-*(1234567890,)")` and  `term = word | number | pp.quotedString`

Comment: @PaulMcG I tried it but did not work :(

Comment: I get this `[[['code', '!=', '720'], 'AND', ['first_name', '=', 'abc']], 'OR', [['last_name', '=', 'def'], 'AND', ['status_code', '=', 'OK']]]` - be sure to take out the space character in definition of `word`. Otherwise, please be more specific than "did not work".

Answer (score 5):

All comments above incorporated in this code:

```
import pyparsing as pp

operator = pp.oneOf(">= <= != > < =").setName("operator")
number = pp.pyparsing_common.number()
# there is no space character in this pp.Word expression
word = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums + "_-*(1234567890,)")
term = word | number | pp.quotedString
condition = pp.Group(term + operator + term)


expr = pp.operatorPrecedence(condition,
         [('NOT', 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT,),
          ('AND', 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT,),
          ('OR', 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT,)])

query_string = 'code!=720 AND first_name=abc OR last_name=def AND status_code=OK'
print(expr.parseString(query_string, parseAll=True)[0])
```

which gives this output:

```
[[['code', '!=', 720], 'AND', ['first_name', '=', 'abc']], 'OR', [['last_name', '=', 'def'], 'AND', ['status_code', '=', 'OK']]]
```

Comment: thx, it's great,  yes, you are right, and i'll add it pp.White expression, term = word | number | pp.quotedString | pp.White(), White expreession default value ' \t\n\r\f' but not allowed space character, ex. 'abc def' or 'abc-def'

Comment: There is no need to add `White()` if you have added `quotedString` - `quotedString` will handle whitespace inside the quotes already.

Comment: and includes space character? 'abc def'

Comment: Try it and see. `print(pp.quotedString.parseString("'abc def'"))`